# Smart Lock | Exterior Use

Tags: smart-lock

I have what may be a crazy idea, which was inspired after both my neighbours had deliveries of online purchases swiped off their porch...not cool. I want to build a box for couriers to put stuff in, and I want to put a lock on it. I have read about smart locks that can have temporary passwords set (some examples may be found [here](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Smart-Home-Smart-Home-Security-Smart-Locks/N-5yc1vZc7by)). Now, my question is has anyone done this, and would these locks need to be tucked out of the elements (like under a roof) so that rain and snow (big issue where I live) wont get on them?

Now, being a new contributor to this page, I don't know if this is a place for product recommendations - so what I am asking for specifically is things to look out for or design considerations other than "box" which is all I have in mind as of now.

Comment: Please note, that I originally asked this question on the Home Improvement Stack Exchange - and it was suggested that I bring it here. Here is the link to the original quesiton: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168875/smart-lock-exterior-use

Comment: this may give you other ideas ... https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xoxhDk-hwuo

Comment: @jsotola, while hilarious lol..."who you had in here..." Not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of these types of product are intended for use on exterior doors so should be weather proof (when installed correctly).

I would point out that they are probably intended to be installed vertically (e.g. in a front door) rather than horizontally (e.g. in the top of a box) where water might pool on the surrounding surface or the face of the product

Comment: True about mounting orientation.  They are designed to be "rain proof" and not necessarily to have gravity pull water in.  Water could leak in through to the non-weatherproof "inside" portion of the lock.